# Efficient algorithm to generate random multigraph (undirected) given nodes and degree

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I wrote a simple algorithm to generate 1000 random graphs given total nodes and associated node degree. Graph is undirected with multiple edges and no self-loops. My current algorithm is very slow:

Graph properties: no self-loops, undirected, multiple edges (i.e. many edges b/w same pair of vertices)

- Pick 2 random node ids from node list using np.random
- Check if node degree is full, if not connect 2 nodes and add to dictionary with connections
- If a certain node has reached node degree removed it from list so it is not picked again.
- randomness is graph generation is crucial as graphs form part of a statistical test
- Algorithm reaches exception, where only 1 node is left out (mostly the node with large degree compared to other nodes) In such a case I take the intermediate generated graph and start breaking random edges and connecting these edges to the left out node until all nodes reach their original node degree.
- This above is the bottleneck I suppose as I generate a graph and degenerate it later due to the exception.
- every random graph in 1000 iterations must be different that older ones. I check this later in the code by appending to a list. If any 2 graphs are exactly same regenerate
- all graphs are realisable given above conditions as I already have original graphs with these configs to start with, I am just generating 1000 random versions of these original graphs

```
from collections import defaultdict

for iteration in range(1000):  # 1000 random graphs
    all_stop = False
    all_stop_2 = False
    count = count +1
    
    success_dict = defaultdict(list)  
    popped_dict = defaultdict(dict)
    grid_dens_dict = defaultdict(set) # final graph being built
        
    
    # pfxlinks = [edge1,edge2,edge3,edge4,........edgen] # just a placeholder edge list to help me identify which node connected with which node in success_dict 
    pfxlinks = [i for i in range(842814)]     # total 842814 edges each connected to a node in grid_ids_withlinks , so if we add all node degrees in grid_ids_withlinks we get (842814 * 2)
    

    
    grid_ids_withlinks = {1107415: 751065,1125583: 15256,1144686: 108969,1115625: 17038,1081048: 6749,1103814: 6476,1108340: 107431,1111992: 45946,1117451: 3594,1093803: 10860,1117452: 2126,1089226: 52518,1082859: 21211,1105613: 94587,1092862: 43891,1083786: 17073,1092899: 999,1141954: 4347,1106506: 2072,1094690: 119736,1116547: 3284,1104705: 2404,1135637: 3815,1121070:16598,1087417: 4514,1103777: 310,1114682: 4265,1091948: 5468,1093788: 2176,              1098316: 2067,1105597: 19090,1141055: 8454,1097427: 3041,1092875: 4159,1086500: 2204,1095619: 9732,1087430: 2041,1112884: 2167,1097413: 17056,1107414: 34769,1111088: 2025,1083768: 2176,1130180: 1886,              1144699: 988,1146499: 6818,1111081: 12509,1104687: 6186,1092866: 4272,1091037: 3,1121044: 39,1098333: 294,1118359: 27,1151091: 21,1107441: 10766,1141094: 3523,1102898: 53,1115634: 2199,1100140: 4347,1086515: 3029,1116505: 238,1082883: 4070,1118366:2065,1102866: 1590,1115631: 4345,1091990: 2131,1144703: 4053,1075589: 19,1081062: 2124,1097425: 11,1133804: 8,1112864: 158,1088307: 112,1138312: 112,1127446: 6245,1108356: 155,1082874: 6315,1115640: 3978,1107432: 2234,1131077: 2032,1115590: 2672,1094696: 13,1136502: 52,1094683: 20,1110183: 2,1113821: 56,1106515: 6,1120183: 11,1083765: 23,1101079: 6,1091944: 12,1085599: 10,1083783: 25,1148339: 6}

# dict with node_id : node degree (total nodes: 93)

    
    for pfxpair in pfxlinks:
        start_put = False    
        end_put = False 
        
        if all_stop_2 == True:
            break
        
        while True:
            
            if all_stop == True:
                all_stop_2 = True
                break
           
            try:
                grid_start_id, grid_end_id = (np.random.choice(list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys()),size = 2, replace = False)) # get 2 random node ids
                grid_start_id = int(grid_start_id)
                grid_end_id = int(grid_end_id)
                
                if start_put == False:
                    
                    start_value = grid_dens_dict.get(grid_start_id)    # if node id exists in my dict and node degree hasnt reached capacity
                    
                    start_process_condition = (not start_value) or ( (start_value) and (len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) < grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id]) )
                    if start_process_condition:
                        grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id].add(pfxpair)
                        start_put = True
                    
                        if len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) == grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id]: # node degree for node full, remove from dict
                            
                            try:
                                #print('deleted key: ',grid_start_id, 'with size:',grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id],'Capacity:',grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id])
                                popped_dict[grid_start_id] = {'orig_capacity': grid_ids_withlinks[grid_start_id],'size':len(grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id]) }
        
                                grid_ids_withlinks.pop(grid_start_id)
                            
                            except:
                                print('already popped')
                else:
                    print('check')
                              
                if end_put == False: 
                    
                                        
                    end_value = grid_dens_dict.get(grid_end_id)
                    if (not end_value) or (end_value and (len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) < grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id])):
                        grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id].add(pfxpair)
                        end_put = True
                        
                        if len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) == grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id]:
                            try:
                                #print('deleted key: ',grid_end_id, 'with size:',grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id],'Capacity:',grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id])
                                popped_dict[grid_end_id] = {'orig_capacity': grid_ids_withlinks[grid_end_id],'size':len(grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id]) }
        
                                grid_ids_withlinks.pop(grid_end_id)
        
                            except: # only 1 node left with large degree, start breaking edges
                                print('already popped')
                else:
                    print('check')
                
                if (start_put == False and end_put == True):      # only end while when both nodes have been assigned a link
                    grid_dens_dict[grid_end_id].discard(pfxpair)
                    end_put = False
                if (start_put == True and end_put == False):
                    grid_dens_dict[grid_start_id].discard(pfxpair)
                    start_put = False
        
                        
                if start_put == True and end_put == True:
                    success_dict[pfxpair].append((grid_start_id,grid_end_id))
        
                    break

       
            except:
                    #print('In except block')
                    grid2grid = defaultdict(list)
                    for k,v in success_dict.items():
                        grid2grid[v[0][0]].append(v[0][1])
                        grid2grid[v[0][1]].append(v[0][0])
                    
                    # ppick 2 random gridids
                    while True:
                        pop_id1, pop_id2 = (np.random.choice(list(grid_dens_dict.keys()),size = 2, replace = False)) # get 2 random node ids for popping
                        pop_id1 = int(pop_id1)
                        pop_id2 = int(pop_id2)
                        if (pop_id1 != list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0] and pop_id2 != list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0] and  (pop_id1 in grid2grid[pop_id2] and pop_id2 in grid2grid[pop_id1])):  ##have an assigned link 
                            grid2grid[pop_id1].remove(pop_id2)
                            grid2grid[pop_id2].remove(pop_id1)
                            grid2grid[list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0]].append(pop_id1)
                            grid2grid[list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0]].append(pop_id2)
                            grid2grid[pop_id1].append(list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0])
                            grid2grid[pop_id2].append(list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0])
        
        
                            
                        if len(grid2grid[list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0]]) == grid_ids_withlinks[list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())[0]]:
                            for k,v in grid2grid.items():
                                grid2grid[k] = Counter(v)
                            
                            if len(all_itr_list) != 0:
                                # check if current grpah same as any previous
                                for graph in all_itr_list:
                                    #same_counter = 0
                                    #for a,b in graph.items():
                                        
                                    shared_items = {k: graph[k] for k in graph if k in grid2grid and graph[k] == grid2grid[k]}
                                    len(shared_items)
                                    
                                    if len(shared_items) == grid_ids_withlinks:                               # total no of grids
                                        #print('no of same nodes: ',len(shared_items))
                                        break
                    
                                
                                
                            all_itr_list.append(grid2grid)
                            
                            filename = 'path'
                            with open(filename,'wb') as handle:
                                pickle.dump(grid2grid, handle)
                            all_stop = True

                            break
        
        print('iteration no:',count)
        if all_stop == False:
            grid2grid = defaultdict(list)
            for k,v in success_dict.items():
                grid2grid[v[0][0]].append(v[0][1])
                grid2grid[v[0][1]].append(v[0][0])
            
            for k,v in grid2grid.items():
                grid2grid[k] = Counter(v)
            all_itr_list.append(grid2grid)

            filename = 'path'
            with open(filename,'wb') as handle:
                pickle.dump(grid2grid, handle)
        

> ##from answer

    import pickle
    from collections import defaultdict
    import numpy as np
    
    
    
    for iteration in range(1000):
        graph = defaultdict(list)
        filename2 = r'path'
        
        filename3 = r'path'
        
        
        with open(filename2,'rb') as handle:
            pfxlinks = pickle.load(handle,encoding ='latin-1')  
        
        with open(filename3,'rb') as handle:
            grid_ids_withlinks = pickle.load(handle,encoding ='latin-1')
        
        nodes = list(grid_ids_withlinks.keys())
        degrees = list(grid_ids_withlinks.values())
        
        while len(nodes) > 0:
            # Get a random index from current nodes
            node_idx = np.random.randint(0, len(nodes)-1)
            # Store the node and its corresponding degree
            node = nodes[node_idx]
            degree = degrees[node_idx]
            
            # Swap that node and its degree with the last node/degree and pop
            # This helps us to remove them in O(1) time
            # We don't need them anymore since we are going to exhaust the required edges
            # for this particular node.
            # This also prevents self-edges.
            nodes[node_idx], nodes[-1] = nodes[-1], nodes[node_idx]
            nodes.pop()
            degrees[node_idx], degrees[-1] = degrees[-1], degrees[node_idx]
            degrees.pop()
            
            
            
            for _ in range(degree): # this is the amount of edges this node needs
            # To make sure we don't get out of bounds.
            # This could potentially happen unless
            # there is a guarantee that the degrees and number of nodes
            # are made such that they fit exactly
              if len(nodes) == 0:
                break
            
              neighbor_idx = np.random.randint(0, len(nodes)-1)
              graph[node].append(nodes[neighbor_idx])
              graph[nodes[neighbor_idx]].append(node)
              degrees[neighbor_idx] -= 1
              if degrees[neighbor_idx] == 0:
                # we need to remove the neighbor node if it has its maximum edges already
                nodes[neighbor_idx], nodes[-1] = nodes[-1], nodes[neighbor_idx]
                nodes.pop()
                degrees[neighbor_idx], degrees[-1] = degrees[-1], degrees[neighbor_idx]
                degrees.pop()
    print('done')
```

Comment: Your post has several problems: the code does not run (missing imports and files), the description is unclear (particularly the graph description), and there's no explicit question being asked. Please fix these issues, otherwise your question may get closed.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have also posted parts of the code that are unrelated to the core algorithm, it makes going through the code and finding bottlenecks relatively difficult.

Here's an algorithm that is faster from what I've seen in your code. It runs in `O(n * m)` for creating each graph, where `n` is the number of nodes, and `m` is the max degree that any of the nodes can have. In other words it's `O(V + E)` where `V` is the number of vertices and `E` the number of edges.

1. Create a list for the nodes, called `nodes`, like `[1, 2, ..., n]`.
2. Create a corresponding list for degrees, called `degrees`, where `degrees[i]` is the degree of `nodes[i]`.
3. Create a store for your graph however you like it. Adjacency list, matrix. Just make sure that adding edges to the graph is of `O(1)` complexity. Let's call this `graph`. A `defaultdict(list)` from `collections` in python would make a good adjacency list. For this algorithm I assume `graph` is a `defaultdict(list)`.
4. Run a while loop on nodes. `while len(nodes) > 0:` and do as follows:

```py
# Get a random index from current nodes
node_idx = random.randint(0, len(nodes)-1)
# Store the node and its corresponding degree
node = nodes[node_idx]
degree = degrees[node_idx]

# Swap that node and its degree with the last node/degree and pop
# This helps us to remove them in O(1) time
# We don't need them anymore since we are going to exhaust the required edges
# for this particular node.
# This also prevents self-edges.
nodes[node_idx], nodes[-1] = nodes[-1], nodes[node_idx]
nodes.pop()
degrees[node_idx], degrees[-1] = degrees[-1], degrees[node_idx]
degrees.pop()

for _ in degree: # this is the amount of edges this node needs
# To make sure we don't get out of bounds.
# This could potentially happen unless
# there is a guarantee that the degrees and number of nodes
# are made such that they fit exactly
  if len(nodes) == 0:
    break

  neighbor_idx = random.randint(0, len(nodes)-1)
  graph[node].append(nodes[neighbor_idx])
  graph[nodes[neighbor_idx]].append(node)
  degrees[neighbor_idx] -= 1
  if degrees[neighbor_idx] == 0:
    # we need to remove the neighbor node if it has its maximum edges already
    nodes[neighbor_idx], nodes[-1] = nodes[-1], nodes[neighbor_idx]
    nodes.pop()
    degrees[neighbor_idx], degrees[-1] = degrees[-1], degrees[neighbor_idx]
    degrees.pop()
```

This algorithm potentially leaves one node at the end that has not all its required edges, but this isn't a shortcoming of the algorithm but can happen if the number of edges for the nodes dosn't work out. I'm not sure how to express is mathematically though.

Also note that this algorithm could produce multiple edges between two nodes. It isn't clear to me if this is allowed or not for the particular graph you are looking for. If so, the code can be ammended such that it avoids such edges without sacrificing the time complexity. But it has the potential to leave multiple nodes with less edges than required. This wouldn't be a shortcoming of the algorithm but a result of how the degrees for particular nodes are defined.

Comment: There is one case where the left-out node actually is a shortcoming of the algorithm. Assume the target degrees `[1 1 2]`. When your algorithm chooses to connect the first two nodes, the third node is left alone with an open degree of `2`. This could be solved by adding a self-edge, but this is prohibited. Instead, you need to break the added edge apart and add two edges to the third node instead. This final clean-up should be very quick, though, if you have an appropriate data structure (e.g., simple edge list)

Comment: You are correct, thank you so much for going through the answer and pointing that out @NicoSchertler I'm thinking that if we sort the initial nodes list by degree descending, we could avoid such a situation since we are going to take care of the nodes which need more edges first. What do you think about this?

Comment: But again, when we swap the nodes with the ones at the end the sorted desc invariant is violated. @NicoSchertler Maybe your solution of cleaning up at the end is better.

Comment: Took me a little bit to understand how the clean up should work, as you proposed. It makes sense. Going to add it to the answer. Please, let me know if you have other input. Really love to learn from more knowledgable people. Thanks again @NicoSchertler

Comment: Thanks. I added the full code and as you correctly identified the issue when only one node is left I start breaking random eddges again. This is infact slow i think

Comment: The cleaning up part for a last remaining node at the end can be made efficient with a time complexity of `O(n)` where `n` is the number of remaining edges that the last node still requires. I'm adding it to the answer right now @skynaive

Comment: Thanks. Also the part where every previously generated graphs are checked to be different. In my code it is here : shared_items = {k: graph[k] for k in graph if k in grid2grid and graph[k] == grid2grid[k]}

Comment: If you compare the current graph with previous ones to avoid similar ones then your graphs won't be uniformally random. Randomness can produce similar results. It's like removing 6 from the space of a 6 sided dice after you got 6 onces. Unless you don't want it to be fully random. @skynaive

Comment: You think I am biasing results by checking if each graph is different or not. What if 999/1000 were randomly similar. Is that alright? My statistics is a bit rusty

Comment: Yes, such a check would bias the results if you created the graphs with a correct random algorithm. Even if 999 graphs turned out equal it is still alright. Randomness makes sense for large numbers so if the algorithm tends to produce similar graphs you either increase the number of nodes/edges or the number of graphs. But just intuition-wise, I think if the number of nodes/edges are reasonably large (which is a relative term, I know), the chances of getting large numbers of similar graphs among 1000 are low.

Comment: @user1984 So i tried the code and it has the exception when only single node is left. What do you suggest I do there? Start breaking random edges? as that is the bottleneck of my code. Your code does not handle this